# parsing xml with lxml

Tags: python, lxml

I've got an xml file with the following:

```
<content_item>
    <primary_keys>
        <primary_key>
            <source>firstone</source>
            <value>123</value>
        </primary_key>
        <primary_key>
            <source>secondone</source>
            <value>456</value>
        </primary_key>
    </primary_keys>
</content_item>
```

Content items can have one or more primary_key. What's the most efficient way using lxml to get the value for the primary_key with a source of "firstone" and the value for the primary_key source of "secondone"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the XPath module in lxml. For "firstone" the abbreviated syntax XPath would be `//primary_key[source="firstone"]/value/text()` and for "second one" the abbreviated syntax XPath would be `//primary_key[source="second one"]/value/text()`.

Use http://www.xpathtester.com/test to try it out.

Comment: I wish I'd known about xpathtester.com a couple of weeks ago!

Comment: Actually, [`text()` is unreliable](http://community.marklogic.com/blog/text-is-a-code-smell). Prefer `string(//primary_key[source="firstone"]/value)` instead. In LXML, that returns a single string instead of a list of them.

Comment: @larsmans text() can be unreliable in some XPath libraries, but I have not had any issues with lxml.

Comment: @LanceHelsten: this is not about particular libraries, but about the defined behavior of `text()` in the XPath spec. If you try `etree.fromstring("<x>foo<!-- -->bar</x>").xpath("/x/text()")` you'll get `['foo', 'bar']` but with `string` you get `'foobar'`, which is more likely to be what you want.

Comment: @larsmans: If you want the text nodes then use `text()` if you want auto-concatenation of the text nodes then use `string` or just `''.join(...)` the result.